# Integrated webcam not detected

Tags: drivers, usb, webcam

However if I try to use cheese it does not detect a webcam. If I run the command lsusb it gives me this output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1c7a:0570 LighTuning Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

There is simply no webcam. However if I run dmesg | grep usb if got this:

```
[    0.335304] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.335304] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.335304] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.558595] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    1.558596] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.558597] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.558599] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-60-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.558600] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.560485] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    1.560486] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.560487] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.560488] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-60-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.560489] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.561081] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[    1.898682] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.047737] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a2a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    2.047739] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.174261] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.325707] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=1c7a, idProduct=0570, bcdDevice=10.41
[    2.325710] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.325712] usb 1-9: Product: EgisTec Touch Fingerprint Sensor
[    2.325713] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: EgisTec
[    2.325714] usb 1-9: SerialNumber: GE0CDD1F
[    4.141540] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[ 1541.348296] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 1684.680129] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1684.855718] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b5c5, bcdDevice=96.18
[ 1684.855724] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[ 1684.855727] usb 1-7: Product: HD WebCam
[ 1684.855730] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 1684.855732] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[ 1684.876210] input: HD WebCam: HD WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input19
[ 1691.137979] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 1719.377673] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 1719.549133] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b5c5, bcdDevice=96.18
[ 1719.549139] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[ 1719.549143] usb 1-7: Product: HD WebCam
[ 1719.549146] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 1719.549149] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[ 1719.562388] input: HD WebCam: HD WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input20
[ 1722.802176] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 1729.138249] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 1729.310772] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b5c5, bcdDevice=96.18
[ 1729.310779] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[ 1729.310782] usb 1-7: Product: HD WebCam
[ 1729.310785] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 1729.310788] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[ 1729.324657] input: HD WebCam: HD WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input21
[ 1732.470691] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 1739.039036] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 1739.214844] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b5c5, bcdDevice=96.18
[ 1739.214851] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[ 1739.214855] usb 1-7: Product: HD WebCam
[ 1739.214857] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 1739.214860] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[ 1739.232304] input: HD WebCam: HD WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input22
[ 1743.254860] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 1748.143734] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 1748.323128] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b5c5, bcdDevice=96.18
[ 1748.323133] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[ 1748.323136] usb 1-7: Product: HD WebCam
[ 1748.323139] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 1748.323141] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[ 1748.343508] input: HD WebCam: HD WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input23
[ 1750.910125] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 2200.689002] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 2200.867050] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b5c5, bcdDevice=96.18
[ 2200.867055] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[ 2200.867059] usb 1-7: Product: HD WebCam
[ 2200.867061] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 2200.867064] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[ 2200.897296] input: HD WebCam: HD WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input24
[ 2203.423790] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 9
[ 2203.747318] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 2203.926608] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b5c5, bcdDevice=96.18
[ 2203.926614] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[ 2203.926618] usb 1-7: Product: HD WebCam
[ 2203.926621] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 2203.926623] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[ 2203.955649] input: HD WebCam: HD WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input25
```

System information:

```
Linux 5.4.0-60-generic #67~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 5 22:01:05 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

You can clearly see there is a WebCam, but I dont know whats wrong with it. Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

```
lena@lena-pc:~$ sudo journalctl -b 0
-- Logs begin at Sun 2019-12-22 14:48:21 CET, end at Fri 2021-01-15 09:21:24 CET. --
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xe0, date = 2020-06-17
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: Linux version 5.4.0-60-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-007) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #67~1
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-60-generic root=UUID=e0831188-19af-4ae7-982d-3aef4c5d8417 ro quiet
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x008: 'MPX bounds registers'
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x010: 'MPX CSR'
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[3]:  576, xstate_sizes[3]:   64
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[4]:  640, xstate_sizes[4]:   64
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x1b, context size is 704 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000057fff] usable
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000058000-0x0000000000058fff] reserved
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000059000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009e000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000723cefff] usable
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000723cf000-0x00000000723cffff] ACPI NVS
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000723d0000-0x00000000723d0fff] reserved
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000723d1000-0x0000000089c9dfff] usable
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000089c9e000-0x000000008a88dfff] reserved
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000008a88e000-0x000000008af7dfff] ACPI NVS
Jan 14 18:29:17 lena-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000008af7e000-0x000000008affdfff] ACPI data
```

sudo lshw

```
*-usbhost:0
                Produkt: xHCI Host Controller
                Hersteller: Linux 5.4.0-60-generic xhci-hcd
                Physische ID: 0
                Bus-Informationen: usb@1
                Logischer Name: usb1
                Version: 5.04
                Fähigkeiten: usb-2.00
                Konfiguration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   Beschreibung: Bluetooth-Schnittstelle
                   Hersteller: Intel Corp.
                   Physische ID: 5
                   Bus-Informationen: usb@1:5
                   Version: 0.01
                   Fähigkeiten: bluetooth usb-2.01
                   Konfiguration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1 UNGEFORDERT
                   Beschreibung: Allgemeines USB-Gerät
                   Produkt: EgisTec Touch Fingerprint Sensor
                   Hersteller: EgisTec
                   Physische ID: 9
                   Bus-Informationen: usb@1:9
                   Version: 10.41
                   Seriennummer: GE0CDD1F
                   Fähigkeiten: usb-1.10
                   Konfiguration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                Produkt: xHCI Host Controller
                Hersteller: Linux 5.4.0-60-generic xhci-hcd
                Physische ID: 1
                Bus-Informationen: usb@2
                Logischer Name: usb2
                Version: 5.04
                Fähigkeiten: usb-3.00
                Konfiguration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
```

Comment: From the timestamps, the camera identifies itself, then, after 3+ seconds, disconnects. Bad cable or connector? Better ways to debug are with `sudo journalctl -b 0`, and `sudo lshw`. Your `dmesg | grep usb` only shows expected entries, it hides the surprise entries.What else was logged around 28 minutes (1684 seconds) after boot?

Comment: Yes that's what I was wondering. I can not check if its bad cable or connector because it is an notebook integrated webcam. I do not even know if the webcam worked, because it is not my notebook.

There was nothing new logged after boot, just the HD Webcam trying to connect again and again. askubuntu did not let me post all of it because of "spam".

Comment: I have the exact same problem. dmesg is flooded with these messages making the system laggy. Webcam stopped working a few weeks ago. Maybe this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed/+bug/1881757